# Material Design icon font doesn't load on Google Chrome 53

Tags: google-chrome, material-design

My Chrome (v53.0.2785.116) doesn't load material design icon font regardless of anything i've tried so far (turning off extensions, clear cache etc).

Anyone solved this yet?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked this question on Google forum and I've managed to solve this. There's this plugin in Sketch (i am not 100% sure if it is this one but I'll correct it when i double check it later) breaks it: https://github.com/keremciu/sketch-iconfont

Everything works fine after i removed it.

Refer here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/kZToEg0WqTU